# Why is this radio button not getting checked?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am dynamically generating some radio buttons like this:

```
 degree_info.innerHTML += '<label for="radio">Current Work:</label>\
        <input type="radio" name="work" value = "project" id="project"  onclick = "addMembers(1);" />Project\
        <input type="radio" name="work" value = "thesis" id="thesis" onclick = "addMembers(2);" />Thesis <br />';
```

The on click event is firing fine, however when I click a radio button, the radio button does not get `checked` set to `true`, but instead stays grey.

UPDATE:

returning `true` from `addMembers()` does not fix it

UPDATE:

Posted to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ELjDg/2/

Also here is my `addMembers()` method

```
function addMembers(num){
    committee_members = document.getElementById("committee_members");
    if(committee_members){
        document.getElementById("degree_info").removeChild(committee_members);
    } 
    degree_info = document.getElementById("degree_info");
    degree_info.innerHTML += "<div id='committee_members'></div>";
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        degree_info.lastChild.innerHTML += '<label for="member">Committee Member:</label>\
        <input type="text" name="member' + i + '" />';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does `addMembers` return `false`?

Comment: it returns nothing, didn't realize that would effect things.

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: P.S. `<!doctype html5` is not a DTD.

Comment: haha, sorry about that, noticed it was missing then typed.

Comment: Can you post your `addMembers()` method?

Comment: @e-bacho2.0: it's there on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set the checkbox attribute `checked` to `true` not just `return true` from the function. Add in your `addMembers(num)` the following code:

`if(num == 1) document.getElementById("project").checked = true;
else if(num == 2) document.getElementById("thesis").checked = true;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, it helps, and I am grateful, but it still doesn't seem to work, could it have something to do with the element not being added to the DOM properly?

Comment: Why don't you use Firebug in Firefox to identify the issue?

Comment: I'm using developer tools in safari

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I haven't been paying more attention to those dev tools, found the bug. When I edited the `innerHTML` the checked was being set to false or something, so I added your code to the end (I had put it at the beginning) , thanks so much

Comment: No worries :). I'm glad you solved it. Remember, always use Firebug when working with JS.